# How to generate doxyfile from Doxyfile.in template?

Tags: doxygen

As the title said, I wonder how to generate a doxygen from my Doxygen.in file.
Last time I use `doxygen -g doxyfile` then I use `io.grub (.., .., ..)` in lua.
But it’s so complex!
How can I make it esaier for me to change doxyfile?

I tried `doxygen -x Doxyfile.in` but nothing happened.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding the `Doxyfile.in` is typical a name of a `Doxyfile` that is used in build systems like cmake to have placeholders for some setytings and especially for the used paths that are replaced with values to be used at the moment of configuration / running doxygen. The configuration is don by the build system (in case of cmake with e.g. `configure_file`). People create by hand a `Doxyfile.in` and adjust it to be used inside the build system.

Comment: This could possibly be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do? For most projects, a static doxyfile suffices.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to generate doxyfile from Doxyfile.in use xmake. 
Since asked the author of xmake, I've solved the problem.
https://github.com/xmake-io/xmake/issues/4163

Comment: In the future, please provide some context. You never mention `xmake` in your question. Why you want to dynamically generate a doxyfile still remains unclear. You could [edit] your question and you could also self-answer. Or you can just leave it as is.

Comment: I want to generate doc by tag before, It's easy to do this with a macro. So I wonder whether doxygen could generate doxyfile from a template. 

Sorry for my unclear expression and poor English and thanks for your advice!

Comment: You'll make everyone's lives easier *and* get better answers if you ask good questions. SO is for asking questions. So no need to apologize.